# Correct approach for async ListFragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, xamarin.android, android-loader

I'm pretty new to Android and I'm finding it difficult to figure out the correct/best way to accomplish the following:

I'm using ActionBarSherlock to have a set of tabs that each load a fragment.  One of these is a ListFragment (actually SherlockListFragment).  I started off by simply using a new thread to load the list, and all seemed fine, until you switch to a different tab before the list has loaded.  Then it fails at SetListShown(true) because I guess the fragment is not active.

```
public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    SetListShown(false);

    var listView = (ListView) Activity.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.List);

    Button loadMore = new Button(Activity);
    loadMore.SetText("Load more articles", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
    loadMore.Click += LoadMoreArticles;
    listView.AddFooterView(loadMore);

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((obj) => {

        var articles = _articleService.GetArticles(0, 10, DateTime.UtcNow);
        _items = articles.Select(x => new ArticleSummaryModel(x)).ToList();

        Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {

            _adapter = new ArticleList_Adapter(Activity, _items);
            ListAdapter = _adapter;

            SetListShown(true);
        });
    });
}
```

What I'd like to happen is that when a tab is opened for the first time it starts loading the data, showing the standard progress indicator, then then it completes the list is shown and the progress indicator removed.  If the tab is change while data is loading, it should be visible when that tab is opened again.

If there's a simple way to achieve this that I've missed, great!  It it's simply not possible with Android, I'd like to know that too so I can stop trying ;-)

I've read a lot about AsyncTask, AsyncTaskLoader, IntentService, etc. but I'm not at all clear what I need to use, and it any of these would actually achieve what I want!

FYI I'm using mono for android and the compatibility pack to support v2.3+, but can hopefully translate any java examples etc.

Many thanks in advance!
Robin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this would work with monodroid but I'm guessing it should be about the same. Use an AsyncTaskLoader since they are tied to the activity lifecycle through the LoaderManager. You should have your fragments implement the LoaderCallbacks interface and call `loaderManager.init(...)` somewhere in there (for example, in `onActivityCreated`). When the loader task is finished you'll be notified in `onLoadFinished` with the data and there you can load your it into the adapter and do the progressbar and listview transition. You can find examples on how to implement an AsyncTaskLoader on the documentation page [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) or with a bit more detail [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html). As for the transition, use something like [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html) which gives some polish to your app.